# Mocha import only

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to explicitly import `only` to fix linting errors, similar to using

`var describe = require("describe").mocha`

is there a similar import for `only`?

Comment: Have you considered using a linter plugin that knows about the globals?

Comment: I have not, any suggestions?

Comment: ...try googling *"{linter name} plugin {library name}"*?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), to fix linting errors, you should configure your linter properly instead of fixing them in code.

However, to answer your question, you can import specific method like this.

```
var only = require('mocha').describe.only
var describe = require('mocha').describe

// If you import describe, you get everything beneath too so you can do
only = describe.only // This will be the same as L1 provided that you have describe
```

On a sidenote, if you use eslint, [eslint-plugin-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-mocha) is worth a look in order to configure your linter for mocha.